# Crosstab large data limit error

Tags: performance, optimization, jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a jasper crosstab report, that returns the following error

```
Crosstab bucket/measure limit (1,000,000) exceeded
```

How do I make the crosstab work to accomodate large data? I understand that `net.sf.jasperreports.crosstab.bucket.measure.limit` needs to be used in the report.

But, this will also have a risk of **out of memory**

How do I solve this?

Comment: Wow. Do you really need to use 1kk buckets? How this report can be used by end-user?

Comment: The data is to get all crops and its varieties for a country. So,the data volume is high

Comment: If you can create a database view that [pivots the data](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html), you might be able to avoid such a huge crosstab. This would likely reduce the amount of information passing between the database and the reporting framework, as well as permit database-side optimizations.

Comment: Thanks David. How would I use a pivoted table/view to construct the crosstab? What will be the rowgroups and columngroups?

Comment: @RathiRao, you  might have to use [Dynamic Jasper](https://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/building-dynamic-columns-in-jasperrepor-1) to create dynamic columns from the pivot query results.